# Using wildcard character '*' to match anything in application.conf Play application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

Is there a way to specify Wildcard character like '*' to match anything.
For Eg:
I want to specify the configuration like this in application.conf.

```
application.*.config = value1
```

In the application I want this "value1" to get picked up for any of the below keys I specify.

```
application.test.config  
application.prod.config  
application.staging.config
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not, you have two solutions

1. You can use application modes (*Dev*, *Prod* or *Test*) i.e. like this:

   ```
   application {
       Dev.value = "My value for DEV"
       Prod.value = "My value for PROD"
       Test.value = "My value for TEST"
   }

   // controller
   String myValue = Play.application().configuration().getString("application." + Play.application().getWrappedApplication().mode().toString() + ".config");
   ```
2. You can create 3 alternative configs for your states and override ONE param i.e. `application.config`, of course you will need to specify required alt. config file while running in given mode.